# How to use � this type of characters in eclipse editor under windows platform

Tags: android, xml, string

I have a problem that I want to write some type of special characters as  � in eclipse editor under windows platform but I can't. How to get the solution of this problem and one more important thing is that when I am using Linux platform this problem doesn't occurs.

Please suggest me the solution for this problem.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Like you wanted to add this in the string.xml?

Comment: Yes Drax, Please suggest me the right solution for the same.

Answer (score 2):

To add � character in the string.xml. you can copy from here and paste this string in the string.xml like

```
<string name="hello">Hello World, HomeActivity! �</string>
```

For some more characters go to microsoft word and insert any symbols/character. copy and paste will solve the problem..

Comment: +1 yes exactly, i was supposed to give the same solution but you are ahead :)

Comment: Ok Drax Thanks but can you tell me how can we write the same on eclipse editor in a java class file with double quotes. means "�"

Comment: just copy from here only and paste it in the java file. it will work defiantly. but it is not good practice to add hard coded string in java file.